# String & Regex manipulation in HTML file using Python

Tags: python, html, regex, file

I am a newbie to Python. I have a HTML file where I need to do some "Find and Replace operation using Regex". What is the best way to do this?

Can I get the contents of the HTML file as a string and do this? Or is there a better way?

Comment: "What is the best way to do this?"  Don't use a regex.  The best way to do this is (1) Search here for duplicates of this question.  (2) Use Beautiful Soup, which is the answer to all the duplicates.

Comment: -1 for asking the third  HTML parsing + regexes  question today...please research a bit before asking. Asking for HTML parsing with regular expressions will always give you numerous downvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at a HTML Parser like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).
Using regex to parse HTML is [a bad idea](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

**Edit:**

Beautiful Soup License:

> Beautiful Soup is licensed under the same terms as Python itself

[Pythons license](http://docs.python.org/license.html#)

> **Note:**
>   GPL-compatible doesn’t mean that we’re distributing Python under the GPL. All Python licenses, unlike the GPL, let you distribute a modified version without making your changes open source. The GPL-compatible licenses make it possible to combine Python with other software that is released under the GPL; the others don’t.

Comment: @cularis I will be using this script for distribution. So if I use beautiful Soap or html5lib, will it be feasible for deployment?